# FlatFileItemWriterBuilder-headerCallback() get number of rows written

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

Is it possible to get the total number of rows written from `FlatFileItemWriter.headerCallback()`?

I am a spring-batch nubee and I looked at [putting count of lines into header of flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458791/putting-count-of-lines-into-header-of-flat-file) and [Spring Batch - Counting Processed Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743529/spring-batch-counting-processed-rows).
However I can't seem to implement the logic using the advice given there. It makes sense the writer count will only be available after the file is processed. However I am trying to get the row-count just before the file is officially written.

I tried to look for a hook like `@AfterStep` and grab the total rows, but I keep going in circles.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<MyFile> generateMyFileWriter(Long jobId,Date eventDate) {
    String filePath = "C:\MYFILE\COMPLETED";
    Resource file = new FileSystemResource(filePath);

    DelimitedLineAggregator<MyFile> myFileLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    myFileLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    myFileLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(getMyFileFieldExtractor());

    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyFile>()
            .name("my-file-writer")
            .resource(file)
            .headerCallback(new MyFileHeaderWriter(file.getFilename()))
            .lineAggregator(myFileLineAggregator)
            .build();
}

private FieldExtractor<MyFile> getMyFileFieldExtractor() {
    final String[] fieldNames = new String[]{
            "typeRecord",
            "idSystem"               
    };  
    return item -> {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyFile> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames(fieldNames);
        return extractor.extract(item);
    };
}
```

**Notice** I am using the `MyFileHeaderWriter.java` class(below) in the `headerCallback(new MyFileHeaderWriter(file.getFilename()))` (above). I am trying to initialize the value of `qtyRecordsCreated` below.

```
class MyFileHeaderWriter implements FlatFileHeaderCallback {

 private final String header;

 private String dtxCreated;
 private String tmxCreated;
 private String fileName;//15 byte file name    private String qtyRecordsCreated;//number of rows in file including the header row

 MyFileHeaderWriter(String sbfFileName) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateCreated = new SimpleDateFormat("YYDDD");
    SimpleDateFormat timeCreated = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMM");
    Date now = new Date(); 

    this.dtxCreated = dateCreated.format(now);
    this.tmxCreated = timeCreated.format(now);
    this.fileName = sbfFileName;        this.qtyRecordsCreated="";  

    String[] headerValues = {dtxCreated,tmxCreated,fileName,qtyRecordsCreated};
     this.header = String.join(",", headerValues);
 }

 @Override
 public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
     writer.write(header);
 }
}
```

How can I get the number of rows in the header row? 
Can the `FlatFileFooterCallback` be used to fetch the number of rows and then update the header with number of rows in the file afterwards?

Comment: `update the header with number of rows in the file afterwards`: you can't insert data in a file inline afterwards. You need to find a way to calculate the number of records upfront and insert it in the header (like a `select count` query, or `Files.lines("yourfile").count()`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in `ItemProcessor`, try this it work for me

```
public class EmployeeProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee process(Employee employee) throws Exception {

         return employee;
    }

     @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
      ExecutionContext stepContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
      stepContext.put("count",  stepExecution.getReadCount());
      System.out.println("COUNT" + stepExecution.getReadCount());
    }
}
```

And in you writer to get value

```
int count = stepContext.getInt("count");
```

Hope work for you

Comment: How can I access the value when setting up the writer? Is there a context where I can store the value and pull it when I use the FlatFileItemWriterBuilder.headerCallback

Comment: @Faiyet chek this also https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html